# Use Facebook to share albums/pictures with a page

Tags: facebook, share

I don't know if it's already possible but I am trying to implement a "sharing system" on my site. Basically I have a blog and I want to add a section where people can share one picture or one entire album so it can be visible on the site itself.

Since I don't want to re-invent the wheel, I would love to do that via Facebook. I already have a Facebook Page for my site, so it would be really interesting if users could directly share the photos they already uploaded via Facebook with my existing page. I thought about using "tags" but it's too limited for what I wanted to do.

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook didn't allowed to use the feature of shared albums (https://www.facebook.com/help/151724461692727/) in SDK, so you need to find an alternative.